# NotSupportedException for custom collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, model-binding, .net-core-3.0

**Problem:**

I have an API endpoint which takes an IEmail input:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("SendAsync")]
public async Task SendAsync(IEmail email)
{
    await this._emailService.SendAsync(email);
}
```

The problem seems to be with the model binding of the Attachments property of this input. The model binder doesn't seem to be able to deserialise to my implementation. This is strange becuase the IEmail seems to be ok...

**Exception:**

```
System.NotSupportedException: The collection type 'IAttachmentCollection' on 'IEmail.Attachments' is not supported.
```

**Setup:**

See below for my contract and implementation for IEmail:

```
public interface IEmail
{ 
    string To { get; set; }

    string Subject { get; set; }

    string Body { get; set; }

    IAttachmentCollection Attachments { get; set; }

    bool HasAttachments { get; }
}

public class EmailMessage : IEmail
{
    public EmailMessage()
    {
        this.Attachments = new AttachmentCollection();
    }

    public string To { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    public IAttachmentCollection Attachments { get; set; }

    public bool HasAttachments => this.Attachments != null && this.Attachments.Any(x => x.Content.Length > 0);
}
```

I have created a custom collection so that I can add custom validation into the Add() routine of the collection:

```
public interface IAttachmentCollection : ICollection<IAttachment>
{
}

public class AttachmentCollection : IAttachmentCollection
{
    private ICollection<IAttachment> _attachments;

    public AttachmentCollection()
    {
        this._attachments = new HashSet<IAttachment>();
    }

    public void Add(IAttachment item)
    {
        // Do some custom validation on the item we are trying to add

        this._attachments.Add(item);
    }

    // Other implemented methods for ICollection<T>...
}
```

Comment: For complex types, Models are suppose to be concrete non-abstract classes with a default constructor by default in order for the action to be able to bind. It is also unable to determine what class to use for the interface property `Attachments`

Comment: The thing is, if I were to update my EmailMessage implementation to use my AttachmentCollection implementation, it wouldn't be implementing the IEmail interface correctly.. Which means my abstraction would be forced to reference implementation code which defeats the purpose.. any ideas?

Comment: Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

Comment: Actions are suppose to reference implementation code. There are only a few built-in interfaces like IFormFile that the framework is aware of, or if you do a custom model binder.

Answer (score 1):

For complex types, Models are suppose to be concrete non-abstract classes with a default constructor by default in order for the action to be able to bind. It is also unable to determine what class to use for the interface property `Attachments`.

#### Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

Create a model that mirrors the desired object graph

```
public class EmailModel {
    public EmailModel() {
        this.Attachments = new List<AttachmentModel>();
    }

    public string To { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    public List<AttachmentModel> Attachments { get; set; }

    public bool HasAttachments => this.Attachments != null && this.Attachments.Any(x => x.Content.Length > 0);
}

public class AttachmentModel {
    //...members
}
```

Explicitly use that for the action

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("SendAsync")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SendAsync([FromBody]EmailModel model) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        IEmain email = new EmailMessage();

        //...code here to map model to the desired type

        await this._emailService.SendAsync(email);

        return Ok();
    }

    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

Making sure to map the posted data to the desired type